# Storing mvc2 entity model in cache

Tags: web-services, caching, asp.net-mvc-2

I getting data from a webservice. (one-time timelimited password used for login)
Data only needs to be read, no updates.

I'm still looking for the best framework to put this in without making the small-medium site too heavy.

If I only gets my data from the webservice once, puts this in several objects..
Would it make sense to store this in cache and reuse it on other information pages?

Using mvc2, would it be sensible to put the entire entity model in HttpRuntime.Cache ?
(I guess session is out of the question..)

thanks, 
nakori

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [EF caching provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers), which will make your entities come from Velocity. That said, it's a lot easier to put stuff into a cache than to know when to expire it. Look into the [CQRS](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/) approach for overall architecture.